# Alembic: run only changes necessary to reflect the latest datamodel instead of all revisions

Tags: sqlalchemy, alembic

A pet example to demonstrate what I want.

Say I have a table User that looks like this:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id =  Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    created_on = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
```

I'm working on a feature and decide it is no longer relevant to track the created_on datetime so I remove that column and generate an auto revision. I run `alembic upgrade head` and voila. A while later I actually realise that we still need the `created_on` column so I decide to add it back, create another revision and upgrade it.

The feature is done and I want to move it to production. I replace the dev database url stored in `sqlalchemy.url` with my `production` database url. If I now run `alembic upgrade heads` it will 'replay' the last two revisions and delete the column (including all the data) and then add it back (column will now be filled with `NULLS`). What I instead want is no changes to the `created_on` column made.

I hope this example demonstrate why this is not a viable setup for a dev/prod split using Alembic. How can I achieve what I want (i.e. not replaying all changes, just the changes necessary to reflect the latest datamodel)? Alternatively, how can I improve this dev/prod split setup in Alembic?

Comment: Edit the revision scripts to remove the `op.drop_table()` from the earlier revision and the `op.create_table()` from the later revision.

Comment: @GordThompson Thanks for the response. Is this really the best way? Then it couldn't be used in an automated CI/CD pipeline for example.